# looping MySQL query result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$b = 1;
$d = mysql_query("select *from 'table_name'");
while($b < 10){
    while($e = mysql_fetch_array($d)){
        echo $e['name_field'];
    }
    $b++;
}
```

I want to loop the output, but I'm stuck. I've tried but still got nothing.
something like this :

```
<?php
$a = 0; 
$b = 0;
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++){
    for($b=0;$b<10;$b++){
        echo $b;        
    }
}
```

Comment: in addition to @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams question, add a space between `* from` in your query.

Comment: and make sure you're using backticks around the table name! otherwise `'table_name'` is a string :)

Comment: @ifaour: No Space between `*` and `from` does not create any issue. That will work as normal

Comment: you don't **have** to use backticks, only when the tablename is a reserved word (or a number).

Answer (score 3):

Seperate `*` and `FROM` by a space. Use backticks or no delimiters instead of single quotes for the table name.

If you want to limit your result, add a `LIMIT` expression to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 10
```

And then loop through the results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($d)){
     echo $row['name_field'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't incrementing $b anywhere.  It gets set as 1 and never increased, so it will always be less than 10.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong as table name should not be in single quote you can use backticks.

if you want to limit result to show only 10 rows add `LIMIT` in query this should be

```
$d = mysql_query("select * from `table_name` limit 10");
```

Remove outer loop

```
while($e = mysql_fetch_array($d)){
     echo $e['name_field'];
}
```

**EDIT**

You might want the result to be shown 10 times. Just put the query inside the outer while loop.

```
$b = 0;
while($b < 10)
{
      $d = mysql_query("select * from `table_name`");
      while($e = mysql_fetch_array($d))
      {
        echo $e['name_field'];
      }
      $b++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$d = mysql_query("select *from `table_name` LIMIT 10");  // use back-ticks and limit in query

while($e = mysql_fetch_array($d)){
     echo $e['name_field'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to output 'name_field' for the first 9 rows (1..<10), you would use:

```
$d = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 9");
while ($e = mysql_fetch_array($d)) {
    echo $e['name_field'];
}
```

If you, however, want to output 'name_field' for all rows 9 times (1..<10) in a loop construction, you only need to add the following two lines in the end of the loop:

```
    mysql_data_seek($d, 0);
    $b++;
```

The resulting code would be:

```
$b = 1;
$d = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 9");
while ($b < 10) {
    while ($e = mysql_fetch_array($d)) {
        echo $e['name_field'];
    }
    mysql_data_seek($d, 0);
    $b++;
}
```